# Problems exporting tibble to ODS

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(readODS) 
source <- tibble(LANGUAGE = toupper(sprachen),
                 SOURCE = c("Source: SFO  National accounts",
                            "Quelle: BFS Volkswirtschaftliche Gesamtrechnung",
                            "Source: OFS Comptes nationaux",
                            "Fonte: UST Conti nazionali"),

                INFORMATION = c("Information: 058 467 34 86, info.vgr-cn bfs.admin.ch",
                          "Auskunft: 058 467 34 86, info.vgr-cn bfs.admin.ch",
                          "Renseignements: 058 467 34 86, info.vgr-cn fs.admin.ch",
                          "Informazioni: 058 467 34 86, info.vgr-cn bfs.admin.ch"),
                COPYRIGHT = c("SFSO 2020", "BFS 2020", "OFS 2020", 
                              "UST 2020"))
)

write_ods(source, "test.ods", sheet = "INFORMATION")
```

When I look in the sheet the first and the last line show some weird behavior (see picture):
The value for the second column is overwritten by the value for the third column. The fourth column then has a NA.

[image]

I removed all tabs and other stuff, but it keeps happening.
Any idea what is wrong here?

Cheers
Renger